# We live on earth. The earth moves round the sun

Tags: meaning-in-context, articles, definite-article

We say that we live on earth but we say the earth moves round the sun.
When earth is a planet and we use the definite article *the* before the names of planets, why can't we say we live on the earth and say on  earth.  Most people say we live on the earth knowingly or unknowingly.
So is it wrong to say if we say I live on the earth instead of on earth?

Comment: We can use either phrase. The article is optional.

Comment: If you drop  the article, it should be capitalized "Earth moves...".